# How to forbid OneSignal to open WebView when handling notification

Tags: ios, swift, onesignal

I am trying to integrate OneSignal into my app.
What I want is when user tap a notification to present desired ViewController modally. I implemented opening VC logic in `handleNotificationAction` while init of OneSignal. 
The problem is that OneSignal still opens its WebView, and I don't want it to. Is there any way to disable opening WebView when user taps notification?

```
let onesignalInitSettings = [kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt: false]
OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions,
                                        appId: "myAppID",
                                        handleNotificationAction: { result in
                                            guard let payload = result?.notification.payload else { return }
                                            guard let additionalData = payload.additionalData else { return }
                                            guard let venueID = additionalData["internal"] as? String else { return }
                                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                                        self.showVenueDetails(venueID)
                                                    }
        },
                                        settings: onesignalInitSettings)
        OneSignal.inFocusDisplayType = .notification
        OneSignal.promptForPushNotifications(userResponse: { accepted in
            print("User accepted notifications: \(accepted)")
        })
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, add `kOSSettingsKeyInAppLaunchURL: false` to your `onesignalInitSettings`. This will open URL in default browser instead of `UIWebView`.

If you want to display your custom view then don't use the URL parameter in the payload. Instead, use custom key-value pair in additional data.

Answer (score 5):

For **OneSignal SDK 3.x.x**

As suggested by OneSignal, add the following key to the project's **info.plist**:

```
OneSignal_suppress_launch_urls = true
```

For **OneSignal SDK version 2.x.x**

add `kOSSettingsKeyInAppLaunchURL: false` to OneSignal's `initSetting`

Answer (score 0):

Search for initOneSignal in project. There in setting parameneter pass

```
kOSSettingsKeyInAppLaunchURL: @false

- (void)initOneSignal {
    [OneSignal setValue:@"react" forKey:@"mSDKType"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didBeginObserving) name:@"didSetBridge" object:nil];

    [OneSignal initWithLaunchOptions:nil appId:nil handleNotificationReceived:^(OSNotification* notification) {
        [self handleRemoteNotificationReceived:[notification stringify]];
    } handleNotificationAction:^(OSNotificationOpenedResult *result) {
        if (!RCTOneSignal.sharedInstance.didStartObserving)
            coldStartOSNotificationOpenedResult = result;
        else
            [self handleRemoteNotificationOpened:[result stringify]];

    } settings:@{@"kOSSettingsKeyInOmitNoAppIdLogging" : @true, kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt : @false, kOSSettingsKeyInAppLaunchURL: @false}]; //default autoPrompt to false since init will be called again
    didInitialize = false;
}
```